# ADF - C # Custom Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I have a csv file as input which I have stored in Azure Blob Storage. I want to read data from csv file, perform some transformations on it and then store data in Azure SQL Database. I am trying to use a C# custom activity in Azure Data Factory having blob as input and sql table as output dataset. I am following this tutorial (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/#see-also) but it has both input and output as blobs. Can I get some sample code for sql database as output as I am unable to figure out how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to fetch connection string of your Azure SQL database from a linked service and then you can talk to database. Try this sample code:

```
AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService sqlInputLinkedService;
AzureSqlTableDataset sqlInputLocation;

Dataset sqlInputDataset = datasets.Where(dataset => dataset.Name == "<Dataset Name>").First();
sqlInputLocation = sqlInputDataset.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureSqlTableDataset;

sqlInputLinkedService = linkedServices.Where (
                    linkedService =>
                    linkedService.Name ==
                    sqlInputDataset.Properties.LinkedServiceName).First().Properties.TypeProperties
                    as AzureSqlDatabaseLinkedService;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlInputLinkedService.ConnectionString);
connection.Open ();
```